# Html table add column with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am obviously very new to JS. I need to solve a problem where i can't change the HTML and CSS-file. From the HTML-file I am supposed to:

add a column with the header "Sum". (Already did that)
add a row att the bottom with the div id "sumrow". (Did that as well)
add a button at the end. (Did that)
add the total from columns "Price and Amount" into column "Sum" when button is clicked
(This where I am lost)

And like I said I can't change anything in HTML and CSS-files.

```js
    // Create a newelement and store it in a variable 
    var newEl = document.createElement('th');
    //Create a text node and store it in a variable 
    var newText = document.createTextNode('Summa');
    //Attach the newtext node to the newelement 
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
    //Find the position where the new element should be added 
    var position = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
    //Insert the newelement into its position 
    position.appendChild(newEl);
    
    
    
    
    
    // Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
    var table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
    
    // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    
    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = "";
    cell2.innerHTML = "";
    cell3.innerHTML = "";
    cell4.innerHTML = sumVal;
    cell5.innerHTML = "";
    cell6.innerHTML = "";
    
    //Puts divid sumrow
    row.setAttribute("id", "sumrow");
    
    var table = document.getElementById("pricetable"), sumVal = 0;
    
    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
    }
    
    //Creates button
    
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Beräkna pris";
    
    // 2. Append somewhere
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    body.appendChild(button);
    
    
    button.addEventListener("click", medelVarde, true);
    button.addEventListener("click", raknaUtMedelvarde, true);
    
    button.setAttribute("class", "btn-primary");
    
    
    function medelVarde(celler){
      var summa = 0;
      for(var i = 3; i < celler.length -1; i++){                    //Räknar igenom från cell nr 4
        var nuvarandeVarde = celler[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        summa = summa + parseInt(nuvarandeVarde);
      }
      var medel = summa / 1;
      return medel;
     }
    
    function raknaUtMedelvarde(){
      var tabell = document.getElementById("pricetable");
      var rader = tabell.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     
      for(var i = 1; i < rader.length; i++){
      var tabellceller = rader[i].getElementsByTagName("td");     //Pekar på de td-element som vi har hämtat
      var medel = medelVarde(tabellceller);
      var medeltext = document.createTextNode(medel);
      var medelelement = tabellceller[tabellceller.length - 1];
      var row2 = table.insertRow(-1);
    
      medelelement.appendChild(medeltext.cloneNode(true));
```

```css
    .table {
        background: white;
    } 
    
    tr#sumrow {
        background-color: #cce4ff;
    }
    
    tr#sumrow td:first-child::after{
        content: "\a0";
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sv">
    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Handling calculations and tables</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header" class="text-center px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto">
                <h1 class="display-4">Home Electronics</h1>
                <p class="lead">Excellent prices on our hone electronics</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <table id="pricetable" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Articlenr</th>
                            <th>Producttype</th>
                            <th>Brand</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
    
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>23456789</td>
                            <td>Telephone</td>
                            <td>Apple</td>
                            <td>6500</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>22256289</td>
                            <td>Telephone</td>
                            <td>Samsung</td>
                            <td>6200</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>24444343</td>
                            <td>Telephone</td>
                            <td>Huawei</td>
                            <td>4200</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>19856639</td>
                            <td>Tablet</td>
                            <td>Apple</td>
                            <td>4000</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>39856639</td>
                            <td>Tablet</td>
                            <td>Samsung</td>
                            <td>2800</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>12349862</td>
                            <td>Tablet</td>
                            <td>Huawei</td>
                            <td>3500</td>
                            <td>
                                
                                <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- add this script as snippet in this question -->
        <!-- <script src="scripts/calculate.js"></script> -->
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Or code is available on https://jsfiddle.net/cmyr2fp6/

Comment: Your code isn't working

Comment: Your JS code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.addEventListener("click", medelVarde, true);
button.addEventListener("click", raknaUtMedelvarde, true);
```

For the button click event listener, you don't have to add the `medelVarde` function.

Also, speaking of that function, I'm not really sure what's happening there. Are you trying to multiply the price and the amount? If so, you can just get the price cell's text and multiply it by the amount input's value (converting to Number the values before multiplying).

```
const [,,, priceCell, amountCell, sumCell] = row.querySelectorAll('td');
const price = Number(priceCell.innerText);
const amount = Number(amountCell.querySelector('input').value);
const sum = price * amount;
```

The `[,,, priceCell, amountCell, sumCell]` is just a short-hand for getting the cells you want from the row ([destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList wherein you can get the element by index.

```
function setUp() {
  // Set up table.
  const table = document.getElementById('pricetable');
  const headerRow = table.querySelector('thead tr');
  const sumHeader = headerRow.insertCell();
  const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  const sumTotalRow = tbody.insertRow();
  const sumTotalCell = sumTotalRow.insertCell();

  sumHeader.innerText = 'Summa';
  sumTotalCell.colSpan = '5';
  sumTotalCell.innerText = 'Total';

  tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => row.insertCell());
  
  // Set up button.
  const btn = document.createElement('button');

  btn.innerText = 'Beräkna pris';
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let total = 0;
  
    tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((row, i, arr) => {
      if (i < arr.length - 1) {
        const [,,, priceCell, amountCell, sumCell] = row.querySelectorAll('td');
        const price = Number(priceCell.innerText);
        const amount = Number(amountCell.querySelector('input').value);
        const sum = price * amount;
        
        sumCell.innerText = sum;
        total += sum;
      } else {
        const totalCell = row.querySelector('td:last-child');
        
        totalCell.innerText = total;
      }
    });
  });
  
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

setUp();
```

Comment: Thanks a million, you are really saving my ass here. :) Just two more Qs: 
1. The add cell in the header doesn't get the same style as the rest. I have tried to set the class "thead-dark" on it but it doesn't work.
2. I want to sum the summarize the input column as well and add the total in the bottom. 

Many thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

Hey ZioPaperone welcome to the JS World :-)

First of all I would recommend to wrap you logic into functions, eg

```
appendRow() {
    //put append row logic here
}
```

Now let's move on to your question, appending a column is a bit more of a trick then appending a row. You might noticed already that the DOM-Structure is a bit more complex. So for a row you could you correctly has added a  node to your tbody.
For a column we need to learn how to create a cell and how we add an entry to the thead. We will use the [insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) method to insert cells, for thead cells that won't work, so we need to add the th with createElement() and append it with appendChild()

```
function appendColumn() {
        // insertCell doesn't work for <th>-Nodes :-(
        var tableHeadRef = document.getElementById('pricetable').tHead; // table reference
        var newTh = document.createElement('th');
        tableHeadRef.rows[0].appendChild(newTh); // inser new th in node in the first row of thead
        newTh.innerHTML = 'thead title';
        
        // open loop for each row in tbody and append cell at the end
        var tableBodyRef = document.getElementById('pricetable').tBodies[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < tableBodyRef.rows.length; i++) {
            var newCell = tableBodyRef.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
            newCell.innerHTML = 'cell text'
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
To sum up values in col u can use the same approach. I broke down the nodes for better understanding. You also might want to add a check if your table data contains a number with [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```
function sumColumn(tableId, columnIndex) {
    var tableBodyRef = document.getElementById(tableId).tBodies[0];
    var sum = 0; // Initialize sum counter with 0

    for (var i = 0; i < tableBodyRef.rows.length; i++) {
         var currentRow = tableBodyRef.rows[i]; //access current row
         var currentCell = currentRow.cells[columnIndex]; // look for the right column
         var currentData = currentCell.innerHTML; // grab cells content
         var sum += parseFloat(currentData); // parse content and add to sum
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! That works sweet for creating the cells! Now I got kind of stuck on the part of summarizing the columns...

Comment: I provided you with a sloppy coded function, I hope it helps you gain some understanding of how I traversed through the table. For any question feel free add comment below ;-)